# Insert timestamp in sql query using python jupyter

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, for-loop

I have a Postgres database that I have connected to Python jupyter notebook. There is a query that I run weekly once, so I want to automate the created_at in python and call that in the SQL query.

```
def get_week_epochs():
    year_first_monday = '2019-11-18'
    today = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    monday = pd.date_range(start=year_first_monday, end=today, freq='7D')
    monday_epochs = (monday.astype(int)/(10**9) - 19800).astype(int)
    epoch_pairs = list(zip(monday_epochs[:-1], monday_epochs[1:]))
    return epoch_pairs
```

I have used the above code to get the epoch pair value, now I want to call that in my SQL query .

```
def daily_user(t_i, t_f):
    query = "SELECT count(id) from abc where created_at >= '{}' and created_at <= '{}'".format(tuple(t_i, t_f))
    daily_user = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnx)

    no_of_users = daily_user

    return no_of_users
```

and I use the below code to call the defined query

```
result = []
epoch_pair = get_week_epochs()
c = 0
for t_i, t_f in epoch_pair:
c+= 1
result.append(
        pd.Series({
            'users': daily_user((t_i, t_f)),
        },name = 'W{}'.format(c))
)
result
```

but I'm getting an error as below

> TypeError: daily_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 't_f'

Please help

Comment: Try - `pd.Series({
            'users': daily_user(t_i, t_f),
        },name = 'W{}'.format(c))`

Comment: daily_user function get two argument but you passed one tuple. Use daily_user(t_i, t_f) or daily_user(*(t_i, t_f)).